# Converting to Swift 4, ambiguous subscript error

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and currently facing issue at highlighted section of code, the error is Ambiguous use of subscript. I tried other solutions I could find on stackoverflow but could not resolve. Please help me understand the error and its solution.

```
do{
    guard let jsonData = data else {
       throw MyError.FoundNil("JSON data issue!")
    }

    guard let dictionaryData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject] else {
        throw MyError.SerializationError("Unable to serialize")
    }

    guard let city = dictionaryData["city"]!["name"]!,
          // Error on next three lines
          let data1 = dictionaryData["list"]![0]! as? [String: AnyObject],
          let data2 = dictionaryData["list"]![1]! as? [String: AnyObject],
          let data3 = dictionaryData["list"]![2]! as? [String: AnyObject],
          let t1 = data1["t"] as? [String: AnyObject],
          let t2 = data2["t"] as? [String: AnyObject],
          let t3 = data3["t"] as? [String: AnyObject],
          let wDay1 = data1["w"]![0]! as? [String:AnyObject],
          let wDay2 = data2["w"]![0]! as? [String:AnyObject],
          let wDay3 = data3["w"]![0]! as? [String:AnyObject]
    else {
        throw MyError.DataPopulateError("Mismatch in assigning values from dictionary")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use `AnyObject`. Define your dictionary as `[String: Any]`.

Next, the problem is once you do something like `dictionaryData["some key"]` you now have an `Any`. That needs to be cast to do anything further with it. The error is from trying to use array index access on an `Any`.

Last, you are misusing the `!` operator. The whole point of a `guard let` is to safely unwrap and safely cast a value. You defeat the whole point by using `!` which will crash your app if the data isn't what your code assumes it is.

Update the 2nd guard as:

```
guard let dictionaryData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String:Any] else {
    throw MyError.SerializationError("Unable to serialize")
}
```

Then rewrite your big `guard` as follows:

```
guard let city = (dictionaryData["city"] as? [String:Any])?["name"] as? String,
    let list = dictionaryData["list"] as? [[String:Any]], list.count >= 3,
    let t1 = list[0]["t"] as? [String:Any],
    let t2 = list[1]["t"] as? [String:Any],
    let t3 = list[2]["t"] as? [String:Any],
    let wDay1 = (list[0]["w"] as? [[String:Any]])?.first,
    let wDay2 = (list[1]["w"] as? [[String:Any]])?.first,
    let wDay3 = (list[2]["w"] as? [[String:Any]])?.first
else {
    throw MyError.DataPopulateError("Mismatch in assigning values from dictionary")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detail explanation. Can you please tell me why do we need optional(?) mark before writing ["name"] as? String in guard statement. guard let city = (dictionaryData["city"] as? [String:Any])?["name"] as? String .

Comment: The `?` before `["name"]` is called "optional chaining". Read the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) chapter in the Swift book.